# actions like 'CCJumpBy' not usable with spritbuilder projects?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

Is it correct that you cannot use actions like 'CCJumpBy' on spritebuilder projects? Since I am currently working on one and it keeps saying "Use of undeclared identifier 'CCJumpBy'" even though I implemented:

```
 #import "cocos2d.h"
 #import <CCActionInterval.h>
```

Is this because spritebuilder uses chipmunk physics, instead of kobald2d? I am sorry if this question is redundant, but I was not able to find a clear answer and I'm a relative newb.

#### Edit:

The method I was looking for seems to be: CCActionJumpBy.
Although I could have saved myself some trouble by looking into the Cocos2d [reference.](http://www.cocos2d-swift.org/docs/api/hierarchy.html), and noticing it is not currently (cocos2d v3.3) listed

Comment: try CCActionJumbBy , you may have better luck.

Comment: in such cases look at the class reference: http://www.cocos2d-swift.org/docs/api/hierarchy.html  note that the "jump" actions were crutches, never really worked well, were buggy, and tus have been deprecated or removed depending on which v3.x you are using.

Comment: Thank you both for the swift and accurate responses. Will update my question accordingly.